# arangod.exe crashes in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7-x64, arangodb, crash

I get an appcrash when attempting to install arangoDB in on a windows 7 machine. I have also tried the XCOPY version and have the same issue. The APPCRASH gives the following:

```
 Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: arangod.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    59704d12
  Fault Module Name:    arangod.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   59704d12
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 0000000000200f77
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: caa2
  Additional Information 2: caa2bb545c0b7fee68e5ff27d1b7f78d
  Additional Information 3: 95f8
  Additional Information 4: 95f82d1cb337322ec0f22184a0acdc62
```

I do not believe it even attempts to access the arangod.conf file let alone object to something inside it.
I used Windows debugger to try and get some additional clues but I'm left stumped. The results are here: http://textuploader.com/do6wn

Comment: Have you confirmed you are using a 64 bit version of Windows 7? [How to determine 32 or 64 bit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/827218/how-to-determine-whether-a-computer-is-running-a-32-bit-version-or-64)

Comment: I an confirm it is a 64 bit OS

Comment: No it doesn't, it's fine running on the same drive. Are you running it via an Administrator privilege cmd.exe window?

Comment: I found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/189495/-imm32-dll-error-message-installing-or-running-a-program) for Win98, same two files as your crash dump. Maybe reinstall the C++ redistributables for your copy of windows?

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks but  I already tried that

Comment: Usually if you have these types of problems, especially with low level files not being the right version, the best thing is to rebuild your machine. The effort to know what the conflicting file was is more effort than a rebuild. To test it without actually destroying your machine, just pop on a copy of the free VirtualBox software from Oracle, spin up a VM and either put Windows 7 or Ubuntu in there to test it. You'll save a lot of time and then won't ever need to worry about having it run natively on your machine. VirtualBox is very quick, no real performance drop for small dev work.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks, that's good advice. Just not quite ready to wipe this windows machine but I now have it running in Ubuntu.on another machine.

Comment: This is not an issue on Windows 10 version 1809

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these sort of issues should be handled via github issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please use github issues for these kind of problems.